# Simulating CPU-intensive Task having fixed amount of work

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, throughput

I am simulating a CPU-Bound task. Each CPU-bound task calculate factorial of 800. Each CPU-bound task is a Runnable object executed by Thread. When i increases number of threads(Each thread runs a Runnable tak) then i found some threads runs so fast in such a way that service times tends to Zero.I could not understand this behaviour.The codes are as follows.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;    
public class CpuBoundJob  implements Runnable {     
    public void run() {    
         BigInteger factValue = BigInteger.ONE;
            long t1=System.nanoTime();      
            for ( int i = 2; i <= 800; i++){
              factValue = factValue.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
            }
        long t2=System.nanoTime();              
        System.out.println("Service Time(ms)="+((double)(t2-t1)/1000000));
    }    
}
```

---

```
public class TaskRunner extends Thread {
    CpuBoundJob job=new CpuBoundJob();
    public void run(){

    job.run();  
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Test {
int numberOfThreads=5;
public Test(){
    for(int i=1;i<=numberOfThreads;i++){
        TaskRunner t=new TaskRunner();
        t.start();
        }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Test(); 
    }
}
```

In case of 5 Threads the output is as below.

```
Service Time(ns)=28.765821
Service Time(ns)=33.489663
Service Time(ns)=29.19727
Service Time(ns)=34.259404
Service Time(ns)=37.347448
```

In case of 10 Threads the output is as below.

```
Service Time(ns)=45.647232
Service Time(ns)=3.972654
Service Time(ns)=23.494475
Service Time(ns)=12.210069
Service Time(ns)=19.382478
Service Time(ns)=15.34706
Service Time(ns)=54.769652
Service Time(ns)=20.646827
Service Time(ns)=3.28936
Service Time(ns)=29.809905
Service Time(ns)=60.798897
Service Time(ns)=50.718839
Service Time(ns)=2.727253
Service Time(ns)=2.882779
Service Time(ns)=63.864835
Service Time(ns)=42.601425
Service Time(ns)=4.029496
Service Time(ns)=4.339761
Service Time(ns)=79.396239
Service Time(ns)=2.923832
Service Time(ns)=5.773848
Service Time(ns)=3.064359
Service Time(ns)=2.446592
Service Time(ns)=2.205802
Service Time(ns)=2.212513
Service Time(ns)=2.265408
Service Time(ns)=82.51073
Service Time(ns)=2.200276
Service Time(ns)=2.289487
Service Time(ns)=2.322645
Service Time(ns)=2.201459
Service Time(ns)=2.217644
Service Time(ns)=2.197908
Service Time(ns)=2.252381
Service Time(ns)=13.564814
Service Time(ns)=2.238171
Service Time(ns)=2.199486
Service Time(ns)=2.179355
Service Time(ns)=2.237381
Service Time(ns)=2.593041
Service Time(ns)=2.444225
Service Time(ns)=2.42054
Service Time(ns)=38.745219
Service Time(ns)=81.232565
Service Time(ns)=19.612216
Service Time(ns)=22.31381
Service Time(ns)=59.521916
Service Time(ns)=59.511258
Service Time(ns)=54.439255
Service Time(ns)=11.582434
```

i could not understand service times of 2.4 etc and sometimes service times drop to 0.8 . why does threads running a fixed amount of work executes so fastly?

Comment: Notes: 1) either merge `CpuBoundJob` and `TaskRunner` or remove `implements Runnable`  `CpuBoundJob`.  (`Runnable` is for submitting to an Executor.)  2) Please format your code correctly.  The location of the curly brackets makes it difficult to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How are you starting these tests?  If you are running starting them cold each time, I suspect the JVM is "[warming up](https://dzone.com/articles/warming-your-jvm-superfast)" and [Just In Time compiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) the code.  If this is the case, the tests with a few threads are running as interpreted code, and later runs are compiled, and even later runs are optimized based upon previous runs.  [The JVM is magic that way](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2078635/enterprise-middleware/jvm-performance-optimization-part-2-compilers.html).

Ideas to make the optimizations less likely to hit:

- use a random number as a working parameter (and not the loop index)
- use the time as a working parameter (ditto)
- throw in some string concatenation
- vary the length of the loop by with the working parameters

Comment: What code i should use in CpuBoundJob that cant be optimized by JIT. i need to have a fixed amount of work that always executes in fixed amount of time.

Comment: You could sleep the thread. It's not work, but it takes a fixed amount of time before returning. Simulating CPU-bound. Unless you want that CPU usage for some other reason.  Maybe better to not use JAVA, but have your Java thread call a system process like a pi-computing binary.

Comment: Excellent! I have accepted ur answer. This is part of my final year project and I am really in trouble because of JIT interference. i like ur idea of not to use java and calling some system process but i never did this  .And i realy need more help regarding this and i appreciate if u plz provide me the liknks that can teach me to do this sort of thing. Or if u can give some example code of java (ur examples) that can not be optimized

Comment: @FaisalBahadur 1) use `System.nanoTime()` as the argument for `BigInteger.valueOf()`.  2) use `(System.currentMiliseconds() % 1000) + 10000` as the loop count.

Comment: oh thanks alot! I also warm up my code  alot to get optimized time .But only last question plz! why is it that after warmup when I run single task it always run for about  35ms but when i run 2 task they run for about 70ms and so on ie on 3 tasks it becomes 3 times. i.e. why is it that when I increase the number of tasks I see it takes slightly longer. I have i5-dual core system.

Comment: @FaisalBahadur Do you mean total time?

Comment: no! For two tasks each task take 70ms .And when i run 3 taks each task takes about 105ms for each single task.

Comment: @FaisalBahadur On average, I could see that making sense on a two-core system.  One core is running thread, the other core is running two threads.  So one thread runs in ~70ms, and the other two run for ~140ms because there the CPU is flipping between the two, for a total of ~350ms.  350/3=116ms on average.  Understand that there is a difference between execution time and run time.  Each thread is taking 70ms of execution time, but the two threads sharing the one CPU are taking their execution time + the other threads execution time, effectively doubling their overall run time.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that at some point the JIT kicks in and optimizes the code. Try running the experiment by first "warming up" the system i.e. for N iterations (you will need to experiment what is a good value of N) run the system without measuring - then measure e.g:

```
public class Test {

private int numberOfThreads;
private int warmUpIterations;

public Test(int numberOfThreads, int warmUpIterations) {
    this.numberOfThreads = numberOfThreads;
    this.warmUpIterations = warmUpIterations;
}

public void runTests() {
    for (int i = 0; i < warmUpIterations; i++) {
        test(); // don't collect timing here
    }

    test(); // collect timing here
}

private void test() {
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++) {
        TaskRunner t = new TaskRunner();
        t.start();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Test(10, 10000).runTests();
}
```

}

Also printing the statistics from within `run()` is problematic, consider accumulating them in some collection and print them once the test is done.

Comment: What code i should use in CpuBoundJob that cant be optimized by JIT. i need to have a fixed amount of work that always executes in fixed amount of time

Answer (score -1):

Most likely the timing functions are too inaccurate to measure such a quick operation. Try the factorial of 100000 or something similar.

The docs of the `nanotime` method say that it's not guaranteed to provide nanosecond accuracy:

> This method provides nanosecond precision, but not necessarily nanosecond resolution (that is, how frequently the value changes) - no guarantees are made except that the resolution is at least as good as that of currentTimeMillis().